# Is 'printf("%n %d", &a, a)' well defined?

Tags: c, initialization, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    printf("abc %n %d", &i, i);
    printf("\n%d\n", i);
}
```

When I executed that, I got the following result.

```
abc  0
4
```

I thought that this result is intended.

But when I execute next one, I got a different result.

```
int main(void) {
    int i; // not initialize
    printf("abc %n %d", &i, i);
    printf("\n%d\n", i);
}
```

which produced:

```
abc  1
4
```

I don't know why the result of `i` in the first `printf()` is `1`.

Even, I found more stranger behavior:

```
int main(void) {
    int sdf;
    printf("abc %n %d", &sdf, sdf);
    printf("\n%d\n", sdf);
    int i;
    printf("abc %n %d", &i, i);
    printf("\n%d\n", i);
}
```

with this output:

```
abc  1
4
abc  Random_Value
4
```

The first one always shows `1` but others show random value (I think this is garbage value).

I think garbage value was intended but I didn't get why the first one has a different result.

Comment: What warnings are you getting from your compiler?

Comment: When printing the value of an uninitialized local integer variable, a random value is exactly what I expect.

Comment: @alk Thank you. but I don't know why it is yet.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I thought the same. But the first one always show '1' not garbage value like above.

Comment: @KyungKyuLee it is garbage `1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of an uninitialized local integer variable of storage class `auto`, that is stored in the *stack area*, is [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/11336762). For this reason, printing it, a random value is absolutely expected.

That's why, in your output

```
abc  1
4
abc  Random_Value
4
```

the value `1` is garbage as well.

In fact it is the first location in the stack, and its value could be different changing system and/or compiler. My **guess** is that its value is 1 because it represents a "ghost `argc`" that, being main a very special function, is present even if the function is defined without parameters, and its value is 1.

Since `argc` represents the number of parameters used to call your program from command line (at least 1: the executable name) there's a way to verify this hypotesis: call your program in this way

```
executableName foo
```

This would make argc become 2, so the value shown by that first `printf` should become `2` as well.

Out of curiosity, I tested this hypotesis by compiling your second example on my machine (DevC++ with `gcc` compiler under W10 64bit OS). I confirmed two statements:

1. When *undefined behavior* occurs, changing environment leads to a change in the output
2. `argc` is present in the stack and affects the initial value of the uninitialized local variables

Output after executing `uninitVars.exe`

```
abc
0
abc
1
```

Output after executing `uninitVars.exe dog`

```
abc
0
abc
2
```

Output after executing `uninitVars.exe dog cat`

```
abc
0
abc
3
```

So it seems that the first four bytes of my stack are always set to 0 (are they the location of the return value?) and that the second one **is actually** `argc`, even if it is not explicitly defined in the `main()` prototype.

---

The second print, instead, shows different values because it is defined after two `printf` calls, and their execution write several bytes in the stack (some of them are addresses, and that explains why the value is always different, as the addresses of a process are virtual and always different).

Comment: I think this is why problem happen. But the first stack of the main function without parameter always has 1, not more than 2. I tried to "executableName foo" but it just printed '1'.

Comment: @KyungKyuLee this denies my _clever guess_. But it must be anyway something written by the os just before passing the execution to main.. I cannot be sure about it, sorry

Comment: @KyungKyuLee Have a look to my edit. I've performed a test on my PC and I think that, even if I don't reproduce your behavior, I've found out something interesting. Useful if you still want to "play" with the stack. (but in your **real** programs the best answer remains: initialize variables before reading their values! ;) ).

Answer (score 3):

The result is well defined. Address of `i` and `i` are passed to the `printf`. Then printf assigns the value to i. But because `i` was passed before it, printf will print the value of `i` before the call.

The latter snippets use uninitialised variable and this undetermined value will be printed first. The behaviour later will be the same as per snipped 1.

The uninitialised variable will have undetermined value. It can be also an UB if the the type of the variable has trap representation (which is not the case here) But because the executing environment is the same, it is very likely that you will see the same values. If you run it on other OS, other computer or will use other compiler they will be probably different.

Comment: It's actually not *automatically* UB in this case because the address of `i` was taken.  It would only be UB if the implementation supported trap representations and the initial value happened to be one.

Comment: I found why it does.
I just run this.
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
 int i;
 printf("%d", i);
}
This result is '1' , not garbage value.
Is it just depend on compiler behavior?

Comment: @dbush well spotted

Comment: @KyungKyuLee Learn more about [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/12139179).

Comment: @KyungKyuLee I have explained why you may see the same values. They are "garbage". I cant explain it simpler.

Comment: @P__J__ You cited the abbreviation "UB" which the most novices are not aware of what it means nor what it does. Maybe you should explain that a little better.

Answer (score 2):

> Is `printf(“%n %d”, &a, a)` defined well in printf?

If `a` has type `int` (equivalently, `signed int`) and is not `const`-qualified then yes, otherwise, no.  In the well-defined case, the value of `a` at the time of the call is printed, and after the call returns, `a` will have the value 0.

Perhaps the key points here are that the arguments to a function call are evaluated before the called function is entered, and they are passed by value.  There is a sequence point between the evaluation of the arguments and execution of the first statement in the function body, so the fact that `a` is read by the calling function and written by `printf` does not present any particular issue.

> [...] when I execute next one, I got a different result.
>
> ```
> int main(void)
> {
>   int i; // not initialize
>   printf("abc %n %d", &i, i);
>   printf("\n%d\n", i);
> }
> ```

> ```
> abc  1
> 4
> ```
>
> I don't know why the result of 'i' in the first printf() is 1.

No one does.  The value of an automatic variable that has neither been initialized nor assigned to is *indeterminate*.  The same considerations apply here as in the title question: The expression `i` in `printf`'s argument list is evaluated before the any part of `printf` executes, so the fact that `printf` will later assign a value to it does not affect the value it receives.

Comment: Re “Reading the indeterminate value of a local variable that has neither been initialized nor assigned has undefined behavior”: No, it does not. If the type has a trap representation, then reading an indeterminate value could cause a trap for that reason. Or if its address had not been taken, reading an automatic uninitialized object has undefined behavior due to C 6.3.2.1 2. But if the address is taken, reading an indeterminate value is not by itself undefined behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, according to annex J.2, yes it does: "The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances: [...] The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate."  However, I acknowledge that annex J is only informative, and I'm inclined to think that its claim is probably drawn, with some loss of precision, from 6.3.2.1.2.

Comment: Updated to address the undefinedness claim and to make wording more precise regarding variable classification.

Comment: All of the compilers I have tested--clang, gcc, icc, msvc--treat that statement from J.2 as normative and also as though the "with automatic storage duration" qualifier were not present. I expect that if you reported this as a bug you would be told that, to whatever extent the normative text does not support this, the standard is defective.

Comment: @zwol: How did you test how the compiler treated a statement in the standard?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Read an indeterminate value conditionally, and see if the compiler assumes that that branch is unreachable. This assumption is allowed by the standard if the behavior is full-on undefined, not if it is merely unspecified.

Answer (score 2):

With the variable in question not being initialized, the behavior is at best unspecified and at worst undefined.

The local variables `i` and `sdf` are uninitialized, which means that their values are **indeterminate**.  The formal definition is in section 3.19 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and is as follows:

> **3.19.2**
>
> *1* **indeterminate value**
>
> either an unspecified value or a trap representation
>
> **3.19.3**
>
> *1* **unspecified value**
>
> valid   value   of   the   relevant   type   where   this   International   Standard   imposes   no requirements on
> which value is chosen in any instance
>
> *2* NOTE   An unspecified value cannot be a trap representation.
>
> **3.19.4**
>
> *1* **trap representation**
>
> an object representation that need not represent a value of the object type

This basically means that the value is unpredictable.  In fact simply reading an indeterminate value can in some cases lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This can happen if the indeterminate value happens to be a **trap representation** as defined as above.

It can also be undefined behavior if the variable in question never had its address taken, however that doesn't apply in this case because you did take the address.  This behavior is documented in section 6.3.2.1p2:

> Except  when  it  is  the  operand  of  the `sizeof` operator,  the
> `_Alignof` operator,  the unary `&` operator, the `++` operator, the
> `--` operator, or the left operand of the `.` operator or  an
> assignment  operator,  an  lvalue  that  does  not  have  array  type
> is  converted  to  the value  stored  in  the  designated  object
> (and  is  no  longer  an  lvalue);  this  is  called *lvalue
> conversion*. If the  lvalue  has  qualified  type,  the  value  has
> the  unqualified  version  of  the type of the lvalue; additionally,
> if the lvalue has atomic type, the value has the non-atomic version
> of  the  type  of  the  lvalue;  otherwise,  the  value  has  the
> type  of  the  lvalue.   If the lvalue has an incomplete type and does
> not have array type, the behavior is undefined.  **If the  lvalue
> designates  an  object  of  automatic  storage  duration  that  could
> have  been declared with the `register` storage class (never had its
> address taken), and that object is  uninitialized  (not  declared
> with  an  initializer  and  no  assignment  to  it  has  been
> performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.**

So assuming your implementation doesn't have trap representations, the values of `sdf` and `i` are unspecified, which means they could be any value, including 0 or 1.  As an example, you get the values 1 and (some random value) for `sdf` and `i`.  When I run the same code I get this:

```
abc  0
4
abc  0
4
```

And if I compile with `-O3` which sets a higher optimization level, I get this:

```
abc  1446280512
4
abc  0
4
```

As you can see, running the came code as you that reads an unspecified value can have different results on different machines, or even on the same machine with different compiler settings.

There's nothing special about the value 0 that I got or the value 1 that you got.  They're just as random as 1446280512.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can not print the result of `%n` in the same line, `i` will keep its previous value. About the random value, while you have not initialized the `i` and `sdf`, they have a random value (most likely 0 but there is no guaranty). In C, global variables will have 0 value if they are not initialized, but the local variables will have uninitialized values (random).